# formating the result of foreach

Tags: php, jquery

fields info: logi_jo[varchar], logi_cntrlnum[int], logi_remark[varchar], logi_poin[varchar]

```
var val = document.getElementById("logi_jo").value;
var val2 = document.getElementById("logi_cntrlnum").value;
var val3 = document.getElementById("logi_remark").value;
var val4 = document.getElementById("logi_poperson").value;
document.location.href = "ppc_logistic-mngt_home2.php?logi_jo=" + val + "&logi_cntrlnum=" + val2 + "&logi_remark=" + val3 + "&logi_poperson=" + val4;
```

**URL after clicking submit:**

sample_link.php?logi_jo=123a&logi_cntrlnum=000002&logi_remark=deliver&logi_poperson=chunkchunks

```
$logi_jo = $_REQUEST['logi_jo'];
$logi_cntrlnum = $_REQUEST[logi_cntrlnum];
$logi_remark = $_REQUEST['logi_remark'];
$logi_poin = $_REQUEST['logi_poperson'];

if(isset ($_GET)) {
  foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)

  if($key != '') {
    $sql .= "$key = '$value' && "; 
  }
}

$sql= substr_replace ($sql , '', strlen($sql) -3 , 2);
echo $sql;
```

OUTPUT: logi_jo = '1' && logi_cntrlnum = '2' && logi_remark = '3' && logi_poperson = '4'

Question:how can i modify the output.. for example **logi_remark is no answer**.. inwhich the prepare **output became:** logi_jo = '123a' && logi_cntrlnum = '000002' && logi_remark = ''&& logi_poperson='chunkchunks' **how can i modify it like this:** logi_jo = '123a' && logi_cntrlnum = '000002' && logi_poperson='chunkchunks'(explanation: if the variables is equal to zero(0) or ''(no answer) it will no appear..)

and last if it is possible if the fields is [int] it does not have '' like this logi_cntrlnum = '000002' it should be like this logi_cntrlnum = 000002 thank u xD

Comment: Please format your question this is so hard to read and understand...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use if else statements

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
    if($key != '') {
        if($key=='logi_remark' && ($value=='' || $value==0))
            $value='chunkchunks';
        $sql .= "$key = '$value' && ";
    }
```

To your addition '000002' is no int, but you can make it to 2

```
if(is_numeric($value))
    $value=(int)$value;
```